# Determining whether a relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, problem-solving, equivalence-relations

The question asks:

> Define a relation $R$ on the set of functions from $R$ to $R$ as follows:

$$(f,g) \in R \text{ if and only if } f(x) − g(x) \geq 0 \text{ for all } x \in R$$

Is this relation reflexive? Symmetric? Transitive? Is it an equivalence relation? Explain.

So far I have that the relations is reflexive because $f(x)-f(x) \geq 0$, which is true.

But I'm not quite sure if the relation is symmetric or transitive as I am not quite familiar.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  $R$ is not symmetric, because $(f,g)\in R \not\implies (g,f)\in R$, so $R$ is not an equivalence relation

Comment: Does the condition $f(x)-g(x)\ge0$ look "symmetric" in the functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: I don't quite understand why it is not symmetric. However, is it true that the relation is reflexive and transitive?

Comment: For example, "$<$" is not symmetric on real numbers because $a<b$ does not imply $b<a$

Comment: @ ph-quiett Consider $ x ^ 2 + 1 $ and $ x ^ 2 $ to disprove the symmetry

Comment: You showed $R$ is reflexive.  For transitive, is it true that if $f(x)-g(x)\ge0\; \forall x \in R$ and $g(x)-h(x)\ge0\; \forall x \in R$ then $f(x)-h(x)\ge0 \forall x \in R$ ?

Comment: By the way, did you mean functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (real numbers), as opposed to R (relation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reflexive**
$$f(x)-f(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Yes it is reflexive.

**Transitive**
$$f(x)-g(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$g(x)-h(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Add above equations,
$$\Longrightarrow f(x)-h(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Yes it is transitive.

**Symmetric**

$$f(x)-g(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$g(x)-f(x)\leq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Hence, $(f,g)\in R $ & $ (g,f)\in R$ iff $g=f$
Hence, this relation is not symmetric.

Hence, not equivalence relation.

Hope it helps:)